Does anything look off about this circuit with a single LiPo battery, a push button controller, and PMOS FET to detect when USBC is plugged in?
This is my first post, thank you for the help in advance :)
Background:
I am designing a power section (3.3V LDO) for a custom ESP32 board. I am using the MCP73831-2-OT (https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73831-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001984H.pdf) to charge a single cell LiPo. However, this only occurs when USBC is connected.
I pulled this circuit from Adafruit RP2040 feather board to detect when the USBC is plugged in using Q1 (https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP1045U.pdf). I also want to use a push button ON/OFF, so I am using the MAX16054AZT+T (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX16054.pdf) to take a PB iput and output a low signal for a PMOS FET that connects either the battery or the USB Power to the LDO.
Question:
Does anything look off here?? Specifically, around having the two FETs in series? Anything I should include to ensure proper operation?
I have not done a project that relies solely on battery, so I just want to make sure there are no red flags.
Looking forward to reading your feedback!
Edit:
Updated to add a shield connection or remove through a 0 ohm resistor and have implemented the change of correcting the USB connections.


Many things look somewhat off. It would be beneficial if you explained how you think the circuit works, so we can either agree or disagree with that. For example, if Q1 is supposed to be off with gate high when VBUS is present, won't CR1 pull gate low since V_ON is supposed to be 0V? Also the Type-C connector USB traces are swapped and the shell is left floating.

@Justme Great point, here is how I intended the circuit to work:
Yes, I do want Q1 off when VBUS is connected. VBUS should pull Q1 high and through the diode go feed the LDO. However, I want it to only supply power to the board if the push button has been pressed which controls Q2. If VBUS is not present, then the battery can connect to the LDO if the button has enabled Q2. Here the diode should be reversed biased and prevent the battery voltage from turning Q1 off.
Thank you for also pointing out the USB lines, looking into that now!

@Justme Here is the pinout for the USBC connector I am using that I followed. I am getting this assembled with JLCPCB: https://wmsc.lcsc.com/wmsc/upload/file/pdf/v2/lcsc/2211111000_Hanbo-Electronic-MC-107D_C2874568.pdf
Looks like it aligns there, will check usb spec.

No in your schematics D+ wires go to D- pins and vice versa, so there's no need to refer to USB specs on that.

Good catch didn't even notice that. I am glad I posted this, I think I had been looking at it too long and knew I was missing something in my look overs. Thanks @Justme !

At least the USB data pins are swapped and it won't work.
The metal shell of the connector is also left floating.
Other than that, I am not sure if the FET system will properly disconnect the battery when USB is applied or properly connect it when USB is removed. Perhaps simulate the circuit in some simulator.

Just updated the post showing the shield connection and the updated usb pair to correct pins! Will simulate and add to the post soon. Thanks again, done have enough rep to up vote but will when I can lol.

@Arachne You can mark the answer correct. But review questions are poor in a way that all answer may be correct - you know, simply asking if anything is wrong could be answered with "yes" or "no" with little explanation.

ah I see. Thank you for the help with a quick review. Now I know for the future that these sort of questions make it difficult for others to provide good answers.

Following @Justme's suggestion to simulate the design, I found a different Push button controller that aligned with the requirements and had an available LTSpice model. Found on the page near the bottom of the product page: https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc2954.html
I then added in the PMOS FETs I chose using SPICE directives.
Here is the schematic:

Here are the waveforms for the output at the FET with respect to the button presses (Modeled by a PWL source) and with NO USBC detected.

When the USBC is connected (V4 = 5V), the first FET turns off and the load is supplied through the diode.

This works, but the diode drop is a bit much making the input to the regulator below the drop out voltage. So besides this, all is working as expected. Will change out that diode.
EDIT:
I rechecked the simulation issues that were seen when USBC was providing power to the Regulator. Originally, the simulation showed the regulated output from the LDO was an issue due to the input voltage. This is true as there was some diode drop and a drop due to RDSON. However, I realized I used the wrong regulator in the simulation that had a higher requirement for drop out voltage. changing this to the appropriate part fixed my issue.
